# Laptop freezes on Dell logo after dual boot and unable to enter into bios settings

Tags: ubuntu

My computer configuration is:
1Hdd, 3gb ram

I had 5 operating systems installed on my one internal Hdd each o/s on  seperate partition as:

- 20Gb_Win 7
- 40Gb_Win 7
- 30Gb_OpenSusu
- 25Gb_Ubuntu
- 25Gb_Mint
- 5Gb SwapArea

**Other data**:

- 120Gb_Movies
- 120Gb_Videos
- 40Gb_Songs
- 40Gb_Software

When I start my laptop I choose OS from grub (purple screen) and everything was fine.
Then today I booted in win7(40gb) and formatted win7(20gb) and made a bootable win8.1 pendrive and restart my laptop to install win8.1.

When i was installing win8.1 I choose the same 20gb partition which I formatted from win7(40gb). And then my laptop screen froze and I powered off the laptop.

Now when i restart:

1. I see dell logo and two options:

   - `F2`: setup
   - `F12`: boot options

But after selecting either option nothing happens and screen does not change. I am unable to enter into bios settings.

Also I noticed one of indicator (2nd one from left out of 4) is flickering at extremely dim light.

UPDATE:
I have removed my harddrive and now I am able edit boot settings and bios setting.
I am running ubuntu live cd and it is running without any difficulty.
Can you please tell me what to do with that harddrive(it is not physically damaged)?

Comment: What is the flickering LED? Hard disk activity? Try taking out the laptop hard disk and seeing if BIOS works. Turn laptop off, replace hdd and power back on -> check again if boot works. If problem persists you may have a failed hard disk or disk controller. It happens. Does the disk spin up?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me - all this BIOS stuff happens *way* before actually booting. Is there a way that you can confirm the power supply is working properly or try with another one? Had a similar problem with a defective USB port - try to disconnect as much stuff as possible and try again.

Comment: yes it is harddisk activity, can I recover data if my hdd failed

Comment: about data recovery: It's worth a try - but impossible to tell what you need to do as long as you don't know what the problem was/is.

Comment: @Tyler17 If it's dead, you cant. Do you hear a clicking noise on your drive?

Comment: I have removed harddrive from laptop and its working with another harddrive.
- When I connect my faulty harddrive with another machine as a second drive it shows up in bios but pc keeps loading xp logo.
- when I connect it through a usb connector into another computer then in linux it shows unable to mount drive and windows doesnot show the drive

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your disk is not broken or dead already, you may want to try this:

Windows just removed GRUB and replaced it with its own bootloader, but maybe it can't handle your partition scheme. Windows is not too friendly with other OSs. So you may want to try this:

1. Run a live CD or USB of Ubuntu.
2. Select the option to *recover an existing installation*.
3. Let Ubuntu install GRUB again to manage your boot.

Of course this is utterly simplified, but I can't find a reason to elaborate more on this since it's almost self-explanatory (and almost any information related is a google away). This is, of course, provided you can boot into a live CD or USB, did you try pressing either option just as it appears? or even pressing repeteadly it before the computer shows anything?

Comment: I have a boot-repair usb 
sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

But as I said after selecting either option F2(Setup) or F12(Boot Options) Nothing happens and screen doesnt change

Comment: Did you try to remove power AND battery, wait a bit and reconnecting power, then go into the BIOS settings?

Comment: @Tyler17 just to expand Jakke's answer, you can press the power button for 15 seconds without the battery and the ac to drain the power completely.